# Gihub Actions On Schedule Cron (Every 5 minutes) Not Working

Tags: cron, github-actions

I have a cron.yml file inside .github/workflows

```
name: 5-minute-cron
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * *'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Call our API route
        run: curl --request GET --url 'https://oscar-react-app.vercel.app/api/endpoints/verify_payment'
```

However, Github Actions doesn't recognize this workflow and the cron task never seems to run, even though I set the interval to 5 minutes, which is the minimum interval explained in the Github Actions documentation.

What could I be doing wrong here?
[image: Error Image on Github Actions]

Comment: Also, I tried deploying to both "master" and "main" branches. But still didn't have any luck.

Comment: can u share the directory structure where this yml file resides ? like .github/workflows/hello.yml

Comment: Yes, the directory structure is /.github/workflows/cron.yml

Comment: [Directory Structure Image](https://ibb.co/mzK7pR3)

Comment: I do not see any issues in your yml fine can test if this works on push ? For me your yml works fine while testing with push this could be the issue where cron jobs are delayed due to high traffic on GitHub Actions . Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65132563/why-is-github-actions-workflow-scheduled-with-cron-not-triggering-at-the-right-t

Comment: Yes, it works fine for on.push. I understand that there may be delays when there's high traffic, but even after waiting about an hour, the workflow wasn't getting triggered. Do you think I should report this as an incident to Github?

Comment: Are you using free GitHub Actions or paid one ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Github Actions workflow scheduled with cron not triggering at the right time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65132563/why-is-github-actions-workflow-scheduled-with-cron-not-triggering-at-the-right-t)

Comment: Hi @brian7989 I just noticed my scheduled job has triggered now. It was probably cause of the load like we had deduced.

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar Yes, I see that my job has been triggered. There must've been lots of Github Action jobs in the traffic. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I feel there is no issues in your yml file as it works fine during push. I feel that this delay could be cause of high workload on GitHub Actions side.  As GitHub says there could be delay is execution of cron jobs its usually advised not to use cron jobs for production as there could be delays hence maybe you can trigger the job by using Jenkins(by using a POST request).

[GitHub Actions workflow not triggering at scheduled time](https://upptime.js.org/blog/2021/01/22/github-actions-schedule-not-working/)